# How do I determine the balance of an address I don't own? (WebAPI or local API)

Tags: transactions, development, address, api

I have an arbitrary address.  How can I get the current balance of the account through a Web API? ... how do I get it for a local API?

I'm also interested in all transaction history for that address.  Let me know if the API can offer that as well.

Comment: Anyone with a local API solution to the same question?

Answer (score 5):

You can query the unspent outputs of an address with this:

```
 http://blockchain.info/unspent?active=$bitcoin_address
```

You can get the transaction history for an address with this:

```
 http://blockchain.info/address/$bitcoin_address?format=json
```

For more information see http://blockchain.info/api/blockchain_api

Comment: Nice, `?format=json` is useful!